# Existe alguma extensão que mostra erros de incompatibilidade com nomes no VS Code?

Tags: javascript

É a primeira vez que entro no Stack overflow, e estou querendo saber se:

*Existe alguma extensão que mostra erros de incompatibilidade com nomes*

Caso exista, vai ajudar muito, eu gastaria bem menos tempo para Depurar um código de outra pessoa...

Ontem mesmo, fui depurar um código e deu um problema pq a classe estava com o nome errado no index.html.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Opa , bom dia  .

O VS CODE é cheio de extensôes desse tipo.

Recomendo procurar por extensôes com o nome **Intelisense** para PHP e Laravel

Para javascript, tem a ESlint

Para HTMl  ,tem umas boas como Auto Close Tag , Auto rename Tags, HighLight Matching Tags , entre outras

Comment: Muito obrigado Henrique!

Me salvou.